# Dynamically append DOM element and if already added then no need to append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically add a div to parent div when a button is clicked.But once it is created another same child div should not be created again when the button is clicked. So this is what I tried to do

```
$("#b1").click(function(){
        $("#d1").has("#d2").remove($(this));
        $("#d1").append($("<div>",{id:"d2",text:"Dynamically added Second DIV"}));
    });
```

It is working but I am getting "TypeError: expr.replace is not a function" in the console...Please suggest.
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to remove your button `#b1` when you've clicked it once. Why not just remove it and add the element when the button is clicked? Like this:

```js
$("#b1").click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
    $("#d1").append($("<div>",{id:"d2",text:"Dynamically added Second DIV"}));
});
```

```css
#d1{
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="d1"></div>
<button id="b1">Button</button>
```

If you really want to see if an element with id `d2` exists within `d1` you can do that with the following if-statement:

```
if ($('#d1').find('#d2').length) {
   // Element found
}
```

With that method, you can do another variant where the button isn't removed but won't work after one element is created:

```js
$("#b1").click(function(){
  if (!$('#d1').find('#d2').length) {
    $("#d1").append($("<div>",{id:"d2",text:"Dynamically added Second DIV"}));
  }
});
```

```css
#d1{
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="d1"></div>
<button id="b1">Button</button>
```

Comment: I want to keep the button.Actually I have two buttons displaying different content when clicked in a common dynamically created div. So removing the button will not work in this case

Comment: @Pranjit Added a variant where the button isn't removed, but won't work after one element is generated.

Comment: using .find() it is working         $("#d1").find('div[id="d3"]').remove();
$("#d1").append($("<div>",{id:"d3",text:"Dynamically added Third DIV"}));

Comment: Is it working? Why are you removing and adding again? Why not just NOT add if already added, as I've done? @Pranjit

Comment: Ya its working in my case also. Your one seems better.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `children.length` to find if a child exist

```js
$("#b1").click(function() {
  if ($("#d1").children("#d2").length <= 0) {
    console.log(1)
    $("#d1").append($("<div>", {
      id: "d2",
      text: "Dynamically added Second DIV"
    }));
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">Paremt Dom</div>
<button id="b1">Click</button>
```

Comment: This one is working fine                                                                                $("#b1").click(function(){   
    $("#d1").find('div[id="d2"]').remove();
   $("#d1").append($("<div>",{id:"d2",text:"Dynamically added Second DIV"}));
  });

Comment: why you want to remove and add again?

Comment: Actually I have two buttons appending different content on a common dynamically created div. So when btn1 is clicked it will check whether there is the common div created by btn2 or not and if created remove it and append new content(same reasoning for btn2). I can use .empty() either but for some reason I want to remove and append again.

Comment: question should be clear and it should contain all the context.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addElement() {
  var parent = $('#container')["0"];
  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.setAttribute('id', 'child');
  var text = document.createTextNode("child");
  elem.append(text);
  if(!parent.children.length > 0) {
    parent.append(elem);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">Parent</div>
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="addElement();">Click</button>
```